# Reloading data on side-by-side UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create an application that has two UITableViews placed side-by-side.  The left one lists article categories and the right one displays article previews (kind of like flipboard's search view).

On the left tableview's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I am supposed to download the article and display the previews on the right UITableView.  However, I cannot seem to make this work.

My assumption is that I reload the data on the tableview before the download is finished.  Any suggestions?

**EDITED**:

Here's my current code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        if (tableView.tag == 1) 
        { 
            //if it's the left tableView (no problem here)
            NSDictionary *catDic = [[Category categories] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [catDic valueForKey:@"name"];
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:[UIFont labelFontSize]];
        }

        if (tableView.tag == 2) 
        { 
            //if it's the right tableView
            ArticlePreview *articleView = [[ArticlePreview alloc] initFlexibleHeightRowForArticleInfo:[self.articleInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
            //ArticlePreview is a custom class that create the articlePreview view, 
            //articleInfos is a variable that holds the articles in core data
            [cell.contentView addSubview:articleView];
            [articleView release];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void) loadArticlePreview: (NSNumber *)_idx
{
    [Category downloadArticlesforIndex:[_idx intValue]];

    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ArticleInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    self.articleInfos = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    [fetchRequest release];

    [self.articlePreviewTableView reloadData]; 
    //articlePreviewTableView is the right table view identifier, hooked with IBOutlet and all
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) //if it's the left table
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadArticlePreview:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the right tableview does not refresh.  I think these methods are where the problem probably is.

Comment: How are you trying to do it now and what problems are you running in to? Please be as specific as possible and show code if applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, if you dequeue a `UITableViewCell`, its going to use the old cell, without any modifications for the actual cell that you need. Change it to so:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}//after this, use the tableView tag to identify.
```

You are also adding a content view to the preview table cell. I strongly recommend you create a custom `UITableViewCell` class when you do this. I found that to be the only way the adding subviews works in cells and is a lot easier to manage the cells with the custom class.

I assume you are doing the downloading in some method in the `ArticlePreview`. You don't need to reload the tableView once the download is finished. Since the `ArticlePreview` object has been added as the cell's subview, when the download is finished in it, call `setNeedsDisplay` when the view is content is downloaded.

Comment: the downloading is done in loadArticlePreview: `[Category downloadArticlesForIndex:[_idx intValue]]`. and i'm not really sure where to call `setNeedsDisplay`, would you care to explain? thanks

Comment: @atnatn : Oh, my mistake. Did not see that. Forget about setNeedsDisplay. If your articleInfos contain the downloaded data, you are fine. Log it to see if its right, and try implementing what I suggested. your code for reloading is right only if the downloading is finished by the time you reload. Meaning, the downloadArticlesForIndex: has finished downloading by the time you reload.

Comment: yes, i thought about that, but i can't figure out how to make sure that the download has already finished by the time i reload the table.

Comment: this is silly. i put everything inside `if (cell == nil)`, and that's the root of all the problem. thanks for pointing that out, and sorry for overlooking that yesterday. fixed it :D

Comment: @atnatn glad to be of help. How do you download it anyway? Does it occur in a separate thread in the Category method or does the download block the app?

Comment: i download it in the method i mentioned above, it populates the core data, then i use fetchRequest to get the data and reload the table.

Comment: oh and i changed `performSelectorInBackground` to `performSelector` (just realized that i should just use a normal method call, doh)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reload your tableview in a background thread. You will have to create a method like this
    `-(void)reloadTable
    {
        [self.articlePreviewTableView reloadData];
    }`

Then call this method on the main thread inside the `-(void) loadArticlePreview: (NSNumber *)_idx` method

Hope this solves ur problem.